# Is division of propositions by their modality comprehensive?

Tags: logic, modal-logic, propositions

I call division of any concept **comprehensive** if the combination of concepts received by such division has a scope congruent (containing exactly the same objects) to the scope of the divided concept.

By **modality** of propositions I mean their classification in accordance with their assertion or denial of the possibility, impossibility, contingency, or necessity of their content.

As far as I know, the following groups of propositions by modality exist:

- Propositions of **alethic modality**, which are about the conditions of their truthness.
- Propositions of **deontic modality**, which are about rights and liabilities.
- Propositions of **epistemic modality**, which are about degree of veracity.
- Propositions of **axiological modality**, which are about personal opinion.

While I understand and accept such division as a valid one, I have no idea how to check whether the scope of these four groups combined will be congruent to the scope of all propositions.

How do I determine the comprehensiveness of such division? Did I miss anything in it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [Varieties of Modality](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/modality-varieties/)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA As far as I see, it only states a certain view on modality, but tells nothing of the comprehensiveness of such division.

Comment: Indeed there may be other categories such as temporal modality (a special kind of modal logic where truth values of assertions vary with time), doxastic modality, etc. Usually we just roughly classify modal logic into alethic and non-alethic categories since the most general normal system K applies in the more general latter case and thus have many different properties/axioms from the former case. Often times people unknowingly try to square the latter to the former like trying to square a circle...

Comment: Hi your problem is extremely similar to the problem of providing definitions, see here https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/definitions/